# is it ok to typecast address to an integer?

Tags: c, casting

```
Queue queue = createQueue(); //queue to store int values
Node *node = getNode(8); 
enQueue(queue, (int)node);//storing an address in the int

..... some other statements ....

Node *root = (Node *) deQueue(queue);//typecasting an int to address
Node *left = root->left;
```

In the above code, queue can store integer values while address is being stored assigned in it.*can it create any problem?*

**what are the situations or any architecture where storing address in an int can be problematic?**

please give some examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> what are the situations or any architecture where storing address in an int can be problematic?

The architecture where pointers are larger than an `int`. That is, most 64-bit systems. You can use the type `long` or better `intptr_t`.

Comment: There's also `uintptr_t`, both are in `stdint.h`

Comment: Right.   The approach described in the question is not a good idea.  Better to use an auxilliary array of Node objects and store the index of the Node object in the queue itself (assuming it is not possible to change the interface used to manage instances of the Queue type).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to go to whacky architectures where your assumption would bite you in the ass, take 64-bit intel arches:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("sizeof int is %i\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof long is %i\n", sizeof(long));
    printf("sizeof void * is %i\n", sizeof(void *));

    exit(0);
}
```

which outputs

```
sizeof int is 4
sizeof long is 8
sizeof void * is 8
```

so, yes, you will run into problems, because you'll silently truncate the high 4 bytes of your address, leading to scribbling over essentially random memory.

Moral of the story: if you're dealing with pointers, use pointers.

Answer (score 1):

With a 32-bit system, the size of `int`, `long` and `int*` usually coincide, so it is not a problem. But casting pointers to integer (and back) in a 64-bit architecture may fail.

With C99 or C11, it exists an optionnally feature : `(u)intptr_t` from `stdint.h` (an integer type which can store a value stored in a `void` pointer). It works on many platform, except for the machine which use ones' complement.

With C89, you can use an `unsigned long` variable ; it will usually work. But why doesn't you use a `void` pointer ?